# np.split() with output from tf.nn.softmax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow to do part of speech tagging. I am getting the output of a softmax layer (it uses tf.nn.softmax) this way:

```
pos_tags_confidences = sess.run(
        self.pos_tags_softmax_op,
        feed_dict=self.feed_dict(batch, is_test=True)
    )
```

POS-tags confidence has a shape (580, 21) and looks like this:

```
[[  2.84045556e-04   1.08584835e-07   5.98690785e-05 ...,   
    7.19540509e-18
    9.11230517e-18   1.95343427e-21]
[  9.98795390e-01   4.86789819e-12   1.50688564e-07 ...,   
   8.64652642e-23
2.89635869e-14   1.35281987e-18]
[  1.54589606e-03   1.40889606e
```

I would like to use np.split() on the previous array and split it by [550, 30]

The issue is that I am getting the following result:

- An array with shape (550,21)
- An empty array,
- Another array with shape (550,21)

instead of:

- An array with shape (550,21)
- An array with shape (30,21)

What could have gone wrong? Please note that I am using the same code elsewhere in my project and works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pos_tags_confidences = pos_tags_confidences.squeeze()
assert pos_tags_confidences.shape==(580, 21) 
split_arrays = np.split(pos_tags_confidences, [550], axis=0)
```